# Is "Love at worship" grammatical?

Tags: expressions

Is "Love at worship" a valid grammatical construction? The intention is to express that love is worshipping, similar to "men at work."

Comment: You can certainly talk about _people at worship_, so this is grammatical. Without context, I don't think I would be clear what the intended meaning was.

Comment: *At work* is a fixed phrase meaning *in action*, *at one's job or place of work*. *Love at worship* doesn't mean *Love is worshiping*. The preposition *At* is usually used to refer to *place, time, direction, cause, activity*. As *worship* doesn't mean *in a worship place*, it can't be accepted as a meaningful phrase. *Love/Loving is worshiping!*

Comment: @mahmudkoya I agree, after all "men at work" doesn't mean "men are work" even if some ladies would say "men are hard work". Men (and women) are more than the work they do just as there is more to love than its function as worship, however significant you might believe that to be. I would say that the OP should use either "Love is worship" or "Love as worship" depending on their intention.

Answer (score 1):

It is a valid grammatical expression, but it does not clearly express your intended meaning.

Perhaps "Worship is an act of love" or "To worship is to love" would suit.